# Mass delete mapped & local printers

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, batch-file

Is there any way to mass remove all local and network mapped printers from all workstations on a domain via group policy or a batch file?

I need to remove local Windows 7 printers such as Fax, Microsoft XPS Document Writer, Send To OneNote 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Delete All option in Group Policy Client Side Preferences for Shared Printers. It's in User Policy.

Answer (score 3):

All printers are stored in the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers
```

Deleting the entries/subfolders there should remove both local and network printers.

Comment: Network Printers deployed through an GPO will not be listed there.